# Push Umbrella Framework to Git server

Tags: xcode, frameworks, project

My problem is that I have developed a framework committed and pushed through Git server no problem, now I want to add a third party library like Alamofire to the framework, in order to generate a framework file that I can send or use anywhere.

So far my options are:

1. Cocoapods, but couldn't commit and push added cocoa pods and workspace.
2. Carthage, didn't know about it much
3. Swift package manager; played with it a bit, but couldn't push the package and other new .xcodeproject files.
4. any other failed ways like adding needed files only, or adding the product framework file from Alamofire to My Framework project which is useless.

So I still need help with adding 3rd party framework to My framework, push it correctly and completely to git server, so that I can clone it or download it from another mac.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add Alamofire with Carthage, doing so:

1. install Carthage:

   ```
   $ brew update
   $ brew install carthage
   ```
2. at the root of your project, create the file `Cartfile` and add the following line:

   ```
   github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.5
   ```
3. run `carthage update`
4. drag and drop `Alamofire.framework` inside your project and that's it.

about Alamofire+Carthage, you can check the official documentation here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#carthage

regarding how to integrate a framework with Carthage, check here:
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-an-application

Comment: I tried Carthage but it was not being pushed through Git server! 
what shall I do? I still don't get the Push/Pull settings much and don't want to corrupt anything on the server for other normal projects.

Comment: @Masashi Apologize, I don't understand. Did you successfully integrate your framework with`Alamofire` using `Carthage` ? Did you follow the steps above? Are you able to build locally your framework?

Comment: I integrated the framework, but couldn't upload/push it through to GIT server.

Comment: So you have a framework integrated correctly with Alamofire through Carthage (`Cartfile`). Then you may want to publish your framework somewhere. Is that framework open source or closed source?

Comment: well I want to make the framework as closed source.but what difference does it make?

Comment: So if it's closed source, you have first to generate an artifact, then you may release it somewhere. To release an artifact check here: https://medium.com/@mkeremkeskin/distributing-closed-source-frameworks-with-cocoapods-and-carthage-44fd141cfd78 and: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#archive-prebuilt-frameworks-into-one-zip-file

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate your help.

I will look more into the artifacts.